# ExtJS disableCache doesn´t working

Tags: rest, extjs

I use ExtJS 4 and a `RESTProxy`. Every time I send a request (PUT or GET) I get the cache included in my request:

`http://localhost:9000/todos?_dc=1355520254945`

Here is my Store definition:

```
Ext.define('MyStore'), {  
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',  
     model: 'MyModel',  
     proxy: {  
         type: 'rest',  
         url: '/todos',  
         disableCaching: false  
     }  
 });
```

I used also `disableCaching: false`, but it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
noCache: false
```

because disableCaching field doesn´t exists.

Comment: it is hard to believe because i can see it in the code:
        if (me.noCache) {
            url = Ext.urlAppend(url, Ext.String.format("{0}={1}", me.cacheString, Ext.Date.now()));
        }

Comment: Please set a breakpoint in the Ext.data.proxy.Server buildUrl method and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off caching globally like this

```
<script src="ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     Ext.data.Connection.disableCaching = false;      // for file uploads
     Ext.data.proxy.Server.prototype.noCache = false; // for all stores loads
     Ext.Ajax.disableCaching = false;                 // for all Ext.Ajax.request()
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```